# Getting vCard.js not a function on second call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vcf-vcard

I have a Node.js/Express.js project.

I have an endpoint that does three things:
1) it uses vCard.js to generate a .vcf file
2) it emails the recipient a link to the .vcf file
3) it adds the recipient as a contact to the users profile

For some reason, when I first call this endpoint, it processes everything just fine. But any calls after that generate an error that vCard is not a function.

Below is a simplified version of the Express endpoint. I stripped out blocks of code that basically instantiate vars that are passed to the functions.

I'm hoping that someone may be able to see something in the flow that may be the cause of the problem.

I can post the entire code, but I thought that might be a bit cumbersome for folks to look through and thought I'd give this a try first.

Here's the endpoint:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Card = require('../models/cards');
var Hold = require('../models/hold');
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
var vCard = require('vcards-js');
var GuidGen = require('./helpers/generate_guid');
var sendmail = require('./helpers/post_office');
var constants = require('./helpers/constants');

router.route('/invite')

.put(function( req, res ){

  vCard = vCard();

  //VARIABLES PASSED TO VCARD HERE

  // REMOVED FIELDS FOR VCARD FOR SIMPLICITY. HERE IS AN EXAMPLE OF A FIELD: vCard.[FIELD] = req.body.[PARAM];


  //FIRST ACTION: SAVE VCARD
  vCard.saveToFile('./vcards/' + req.body.invited_first_name + req.body.invited_last_name + req.body.owner_id + '.vcf');


  //SECOND ACTION: SEND EMAIL WITH VCARD

 //FOLLOWING ACTION PASSES THE ABOVE PARAMS AND SENDS EMAIL VIA HELPER
  sendmail.mailsend(emailSender, emailRecipient, emailSubject, emailBody);


  //THIRD ACTION: SAVE CONTACT TO USER PROFILE
  Profile.findOne({'contacts.emails.email_address':req.body.invited_email}, function(err, profile){
    if(err)
      console.log('Error in looking for profile.');

    if(profile){

        //I REMOVED THE CODE BLOCK THAT SETS UP SAVING THE PROFILE FOR SIMPLICITY

          profile.save(function(err){
            if(err)
              res.send(err);
            res.json(profile);
          });

    } else {


      //REMOVED CODE FOR SETTING UP UPDATING CONTACTS FOR SIMPLICITY 


      var contacts = {
          //CODE FOR CONTATACTS REMOVED FOR SIMPLICITY
      };

      Profile.findOneAndUpdate({
          owner_id: req.body.owner_id
      }, {
          $push: {
              contacts: contacts
          }
      }, {
          new: true
      }, (err, profile) => {
          if (err) {
              return res.send(err);
          }
          return res.json(profile);
      });

      }

    })


})




module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because every time .put is called, it's referencing the global `vCard` reference. On the first line, you set the global vCard to the function execution of vCard - that's you're mistake. When you come back to the second `put`, you reference the global `vCard`, but this time, it's an object because you set it as such on the first call.

That's a little confusing, let me break it down.

1. vCard is a reference to the module `vcards-js`.
2. vCard is a function.
3. vCard is an object with the return from `vCard()`.
4. You tried to invoke a function call on an object, which was returned form the original call of `vCard`.

In this instance, you should either rename vCard to something else, or hoist the new declaration of `vCard` outside of your `put` method.